# missing ; before statement error while creating object in javascript by getting data from database in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

While creating object in javascript by getting data from database and adding it to a string to make it a object notation and finally using JSON.parse() to convert to an object, there is an error in the below mentioned line(var txt1 = ..).

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    //some code here
const myQuestions = [];
<%
try
{
  // create a mysql database connection
  String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/examination";
  Class.forName(myDriver);
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");
  String table = request.getParameter("examname");
  PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from "+table);

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            String ques,op1,op2,op3;
            int correct;

    while (rs.next()) {

                 ques = rs.getString("question");
                 op1 = rs.getString("op1");
                 op2 = rs.getString("op2");
                 op3 = rs.getString("op3");
                 correct = rs.getInt("correct");



           %>

             var txt1 = '{"question":"'+<%=ques%>+'" , "answers":{"a":"'+<%=op1%>+'", "b":"'+<%=op2%>+'" , "c":"'+<%=op3%>+'"}, "correctAnswer":'+<%=correct%>+'}'; // error occurs in this line
             var o = JSON.parse(txt1);
             myQuestions.push(o);



<%  }


           conn.close();

    }


catch (Exception e)
{
  System.err.println("Got an exception!");
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
%>
</script>
```